# UWP Brokered Component Restart/Stop DLL

Tags: c#, printing, uwp, com, components

so I'm implementing printing for my UWP app following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps#creating-and-deploying-the-windows-runtime-proxy

I have a bug where the printer stops working and I realized one fix is to go into task manager and delete the COM Surrogate associated with a dll. I'm not sure how to find out what dll this is, has anyone ran into this issue before?

I would think the fix is to relink the component somehow but am not sure how.

Comment: Found out the dll is from C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64 using process manager

Comment: As an alternative to using brokered components, you could use a desktop extension for your UWP. Here is a tutorial: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

And here is a simple sample for printing using this technique: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnOsbzlRfghOikDy8Dw

Comment: Hey Stefan, does this solution work with side-loaded applications? Also, is this the same or an alternative implementation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app?

Also if you have any input to what kennyzx commented about killing the dllhost.exe that would be awesome.

Comment: The link you provided is the right modern way. It has the limitation though that you can't do silent/unattended printing. I was assuming that's why you took the brokered component route. If that's not the case, then by all means you should start with the modern API.

To answer your question: my alternative (which would allow silent printing) works for both side-load and store distribution. Regarding brokered components I will say that this is Win8 tech that is not actively encouraged/recommended. Using a desktop extension would be preferred over a brokered component.

Comment: Good to know - I was not aware of that - thanks again for the info and two solutions Stefan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to print from a UWP is using the Windows.Graphics.Printing, Windows.UI.Xaml.Printing, PrintDocument APIs as documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app

One thing to note is that this approach currently does not support silent/unattended print scenarios. For those you would have to work around using classic Win32 printing API, either from a brokered component (as you tried) or using a desktop extension to your UWP. The latter is the preferred route (brokered components is Win8 era tech). I have a quick tutorial on desktop extensions here: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/ and a very simple silent printing sample here: [1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnOsbzlRfghOikDy8Dw](http://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNnOsbzlRfghOikDy8Dw)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this technique (Brokered Windows Runtime Components) in an LOB app for several years, and it is always a PITA for the maintenance.

Every time I have made an update to `Brokered Windows Runtime Component` I will need to register it again using regsvr32.exe. If I have run the app and COM Surrogate is already running, the registration will fail. I will need to reboot the system, or I have to kill the running "dllhost.exe" in task manager - there might be several instances of `dllhost.exe`, and I just kill the ones that run under the current logon user, and leave those run as SYSTEM.

One of the *dllhost.exe* instances hosts the DLL you created and registered. It is not clear why printer stops working so I can't give an answer. To help investigation, add some logs to these points.

1. When the app code is calling the Brokered Windows Runtime Component, check the return value of the call, and try and catch any exception.
2. Inside the Brokered Windows Runtime Component, at the entry and exit of the method that is being called by the App.
3. Check the code that uses printer, is it working correctly? or is it being called at all?

Comment: Actually my investigation lead me to exactly what you described. The problem is the re-registering with regsvr32.exe and I found the same solution of killing it in task manager.

Do you know of any solution to do this through code, or is this not possible?

Comment: Try finding dllhost.exe processes by name (“dllhost”, not including the extension), and listing the modules that have been loaded by each process (checking Process.Modules property), if you find your ProxyStub dll in the module list, then kill the process.

Comment: This [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090212-00/?p=19173) explains what COM surrogate does, I assume it is safe to kill it without serious side effects like affecting the functionality of other processes.